# Can I set the sidenotes on a Tufte-style handout to the left side of the page?

Tags: tufte, sidenotes

In addition, is it possible to have the side of the page on which the sidenotes appear alternate such that, for even-numbered pages, the notes will be to the left, while for odd-numbered pages, they will be to the right?

Comment: In addition to what? Please include a Minimum Working Example which people can compile and work on easily. This will help you to attract useful responses to your question by making it easy for people to understand the problem and to work on it. Did you pass the class the `twoside` option?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `symmetric` document class option:

```
\documentclass[symmetric]{tufte-handout}
```